# Using Powershell, How to access outlook highest-level folders?

Tags: powershell

I want to obtain some data from within a folder called "FDA UFMS User Provision", my PS code is here:

```
$sentMail = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6) # == olFolderSentMail
$bigFolder = $sentMail.Parent


$ufms = "FDA UFMS User Provision"


$newufms = $bigFolder.folders.item($ufms)


$newufms.Items | %{ $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject, "Request\s\d{6}"); if ($RESULT.Success)

{$RESULT.Value}} | %{$Result=[Regex]::Match($_, "\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value}} | Out-File C:\Temp

\Powershell_6_digit_Codes.txt -Append
```

But the problem is that it is getting the "UFMS" folder which is under Inbox. However I want to access the higher-level "UFMS"  folder (happens to be a shared network email box)

In the picture, the arrow points to the email box I want to access, which is called "FDA UFMS User Provision" and is level with the "Adel" outlook folder:

**What I tried so far**

```
$newuf = $outlook.Session.Folders.Item("FDA UFMS User Provision").item

$newuf.Items | | %{ $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject,"Request\s\d{6}"); if ($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value}} | %{$Result=[Regex]::Match($_, "\d{6}");if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value}} | Out-File C:\Temp\Powershell_6_digit_Codes_ULF.txt -Append
```

[image]

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting folders is really very simple. You simply have to walk down from the root account through the folder path one by one. Here is what you would need to do for that folder:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$MyAcct = $Namespace.Folders | ?{$_.Name -match $env:USERNAME}
$UFMS = $MyAcct.Folders | ?{$_.Name -match "FDA UFMS User Provision"}
```

That does assume that your user name is in your email address, so if my user name is TMTech then my email address would be something like TMTech@awesomesauce.com.

If you wanted a folder inside that one, you would add a line like:

```
$OtherFldr = $UFMS.Folders | Where{$_.Name -match "Other Folder"}
```

**Edit:** Ok, I just noticed where you said it's a shared mailbox. In that case change what I just said... To find a mailbox other than your own we need to change the `$MyAcct =` line. So it would become:

```
$SharedMB = $NameSpace.Folders | Where{$_.Name -match "FDA UFMS User Provision"}
```

Now `$SharedMB` should be the root of that mailbox, then you would get the inbox as described above, or whatever folder you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure why , but this doesn't capture the information I'm looking for  . So you're saying the last 2 lines in the first block of code become : `$SharedMB = $NameSpace.Folders | Where{$_.Name -match "FDA UFMS User Provision"}
$UFMS = $SharedMB.Folders | ?{$_.Name -match "FDA UFMS User Provision"}`

Comment: No, the `$SharedMB=` line gets you the shared mailbox account, from there you would need to find the folder within that account that contains the mail you want (such as Inbox). You should be able to get to that point, and just do `$SharedMB.Folders | Select Name` to see what your options are.

Comment: It paused at the PS command line, because it's loading text file up even as we speak